# How to handle php loop through elements with jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have an HTML form that will return as HTML format with JQuery Ajax after the insertion query is successful.

comment.php

```
$post_id=$_POST['id'];
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO comment(comment,post_id,)VALUES('$comment','$post_id')");
if(!mysql_errno()){
?>
<p><?php echo $comment; ?></p>
```

This is my JQuery code that will send the request and values and return the HTML form after the insertion query succeeds.

index.php

```
// on post comment click 
    $('.bt-add-com').click(function(){
        var theCom=$(this).siblings('.the-new-com');
        if(!theCom.val()){ 
            alert('You need to write a comment!'); 
        }else{
        var post_id=$(this).parents(".post_id").attr("id");
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "comment.php",
                data: "act=add-com&comment="+theCom.val()+"&id="+post_id,
                success: function(html){
                    theCom.val('');
                    $('.the-new-com').hide('fast', function(){
                        $('.new-comment-line').show('fast');
                        $('.new-comment-line').after(html);  
                    });
                }  
            });
        }
    });
```

This my form. It's running within a loop of posts submitted by the user every time.

```
<form action="" method="POST" class="post_id" id="<?php echo $post_id; ?>">

    <span>Write a comment ...</span>
    </div>
    <div class="new-comment-line"></div><----here is a line before the comment initiates..--->
        <textarea class="the-new-com"></textarea>
        <div class="bt-add-com">Post comment</div>
</form>
```

And now my question is that my all code works very well except last few lines of JQuery code.

```
$('.new-comment-line').after(html);
```

The line of code when my form returns the HTML form from comment.php after the Ajax request has the problem. The form prints every time, in every post, that the user submitted the status.

How should I handle the form? I want my comments to print every time only in the specific post submitted by the user.

Comment: Please use Mysqli or PDO as mysql is deprecated in newer PHP versions, and escape your variables inside the query. Your code is not injection proof at all. More info on how to do that: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Comment: Bro! I know very well that mysql is now depreciated version. My all quest is not all about php,, its about jquery related, and this just a sample of code to make this easier to understand,, and i am also using mysqli procedural.. So please give me the the solution how to handle loop through form with jquery, i have just same class of many elements that created in loop.. So how can i handle specific elements on specific click events on each form. Thats all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously $('.new-comment-line') is a class selector and you are selecting all elements in this class. As you start your function by clicking on a button, I suggest the selection of correct element relative to the clicked button. So immediately after clicking a button, select the correct element:

```
var correctElement=$(this).siblings('.new-comment-line');
```

and then add the html to it when needed:

```
correctElement.after(html);
```